# Send an ajax request only when data has to be loaded for the first time

Tags: ajax, extjs, tree, request, accordion

I have a question.
I have been working with `Ext JS` for quiet a while and I just couldn't figure out how to solve this issue.
I have a tree with some nodes and when I click on this node, a tab will be created.
In the tree, I have a node called `APPLICATION STATUS` which has three sub nodes `CLASSIC` `BULK` and `WIZARD`.
And when the tab is created, the first accordion expands and the values are loaded.
There are totally 5 accordions namely `DEV`, `QA`, `INT`, `STG`, `PROD`.
So first initially when I click on the tree node, `CLASSIC` - `DEV` is loaded.
After that if I click on `QA` accordion, `CLASSIC` - `QA` loads.
Now when I switch back to `CLASSIC` - `DEV` , I don't want to send the request once again and fetch the data, instead wanna just display the data as such.
This should be applicable for all the tree nodes - accordion combination.
Just help me to how do I solve this??.

Answer (score 0):

Create the tab panels once and hide or show them when clicked using `panel.setVisible( false );`

Your function that creates a tab when you click a node may create a tab only once and then mark it as created by `push`ing it to an tab array `panels`.

So when you click a node, the function will

1. hide all panels in `panels` using `panel.setVisible( false );` and
2. create the panel if not yet created, and if created only show it via `panel.setVisible( true );`